# Best effort for injecting exceptions in C# and C++ combined environment?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2010, exception, nunit

I have a CLI project built using both C# and C++. I am using Visual Studio 2010 and it has a feature of building Testing APIs. Since there are APIs in my project which are meant to be platform independent (Any platform), I am not able to proceed with Visual Studios Testing API. I know nUnit is another way to do it, but it will be a happy way testing.

I want to dig out means of injecting errors into the CLI with the help of flags so that I can reach out code which nUnit can not. Anyone having a brief idea, how this could be achieved ? Also I need to design a framework which can accommodate any future changes to code.

Thanks in advance.